# Fatal error in composer during payment form install - Magento ver. 2.3.1 - PHP 7.2

Tags: magento2

please, someone can help me here?

`composer require pagseguro/magento2`

Using version ^1.12 for `pagseguro/magento2`
./composer.json has been updated

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Magento\InventoryComposerInstaller\Plugin_composer_tmp1::initModuleDeployment() must be an instance of Magento\InventoryComposerInstaller\void, none returned in phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Plugin/PluginManager.php(195) : eval()'d code:69

Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Magento\InventoryComposerInstaller\Plugin_composer_tmp1->initModuleDeployment(Object(Composer\Script\Event))
#1 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(176): call_user_func(Array, Object(Composer\Script\Event))
#2 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(96): Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(Object(Composer\Script\Event))
#3 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php(204): Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatchScript('pre-update-cmd', true)
#4 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Command/RequireCommand.php(18 in phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Plugin/PluginManager.php(195) : eval()'d code on line 69
```